# Cannot do anything with my tables in postgresql 9.6?

Tags: postgresql

Here is a video demo:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YUMRGV8WYSo&feature=youtu.be

None of the following works:

```
\d table_name;
\d+ table_name;
select * from table_name;
```

Although the tables can be listed using `\dt`.

macOS sierra, postgresql 9.6.1 (installed via brew)

Any idea what went wrong?

Comment: SQL queries need to be terminated with a `;` otherwise it won't be executed

Comment: Yeah, I did that in the video. Code is corrected now.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what happened, but restarting the service solves the problem:

```
pg_ctl -D ~/db_dir/ stop
pg_ctl -D ~/db_dir/ start
```

Comment: When a query appears to be hanging for no good reason, 9 times out of 10 it's just waiting to acquire a lock. If that's the case, [`pg_locks`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/view-pg-locks.html) and [`pg_stat_activity`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/monitoring-stats.html#PG-STAT-ACTIVITY-VIEW) should reveal the cause. Presumably your server restart killed the offending transaction.